# SQL Query, return field_w where field_x is max -- group by field_y, field_z

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For each 'Date' and 'Price', I would like to have the 'Length' of the max '#'

I tried to do a partition by and group by but my results were inaccurate.

Please help.[image]

Comment: Please show us sample data and expected output so we are sure to understand your requirement.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are really using.  Redshift and Postgres are not equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date, price order by # desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This will work in any database that supports window functions.  In Postgres, though, I would use `distinct on`.